# Driving from Bucharest to Balchik

Tags: driving, romania, bulgaria

We're going in vacation to Balchik, Bulgaria between 4-8th July, and I would like to know whether this is the shortest path and how good is the road ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid too late now for your July trip but according to © Google Maps there is a route that is 64 km shorter (and about 20 minutes quicker) and another (E81 all the way) that though only 9 km shorter is a further 22 minutes quicker. There is also at least one other option that is both quicker and shorter:

[image: TSE7130 example]

Judging by a quick look with Pegman, the road surfaces are very good, though the E81 can carry more traffic than the E70/A2.

Comment: Thank you @pnuts , will use that route next time. This time I took the Bulgarian highway A2, the road was fine. I got there in 4h and 15 minutes.